# Upload a file to an IPFS node from Google Apps Script

Tags: api, google-apps-script, ipfs

I'm trying to upload a file to an IPFS node using Google Apps Script (GAS) without success.
However, I was able to upload a file successfully using Postman. Unfortunately Postman only gives back the source code snippet closest to GAS as a JavaScript - Fetch code, which is not working as is in GAS.

In GAS, the authentication part is working and I know that because if I'm changing the bearer token, then I'm getting invalid credentials error instead of "Invalid request format".

Test code attached where I'm getting the "Invalid request format" error from the server.

For testing purpose, the file which needs to be uploaded, could be created on the fly with the script, but has to be one from Google Drive eventually.

```
function test() {
  
  let myHeaders = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ...'};
  let fileBlob = Utilities.newBlob('Hello!', 'text/plain', 'TestFile.txt');
  let formdata = {'file': fileBlob,
                  'pinataMetadata': {'name': 'TestFileNewName.txt','keyvalues': {'MetaData1': 'Test1', 'MetaData2': 'Test2'}},
                  'pinataOptions': {'cidVersion': 0}};

  let requestOptions = {
    method: 'post',
    headers: myHeaders,
    papyload: formdata,
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };

  let url = "https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS";

  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);
  let responeText = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  Logger.log(responeText);
}
```

Comment: Who is papy????

Comment: Sorry that I missed your comment @TheMaster, actually you were the first one that found the typo. Thank you for it, that was the only problem with the script. After the fix it started to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your access token of `Bearer ...` is the valid value for using the API, how about the following modification? From [the official document](https://docs.pinata.cloud/api-pinning/pin-file), I thought that in the case of your `formdata`, the values of `pinataMetadata` and `pinataOptions` might be required to be the string type.

#### From:

```
let formdata = {'file': fileBlob,
                'pinataMetadata': {'name': 'TestFileNewName.txt','keyvalues': {'MetaData1': 'Test1', 'MetaData2': 'Test2'}},
                'pinataOptions': {'cidVersion': 0}};
```

#### To:

```
let formdata = {
  'file': fileBlob,
  'pinataMetadata': JSON.stringify({ 'name': 'TestFileNewName.txt', 'keyvalues': { 'MetaData1': 'Test1', 'MetaData2': 'Test2' } }),
  'pinataOptions': JSON.stringify({ 'cidVersion': 0 })
};
```

And also, please modify `papyload: formdata,` to `payload: formdata,`. This has already been mentioned by 
[TheMaster's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70058641/upload-a-file-to-an-ipfs-node-from-google-apps-script#comment123844650_70058641).

#### References:

- [Pin File](https://docs.pinata.cloud/api-pinning/pin-file)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: Thank you Tanaike,

I could cry now as I haven't seen the typo in the formdata. I just needed to fix the papyload to payload and the script started to work. Thank you again for pointing out the typo!